Is there a way to stop running pd.read_sql?
I have form where user enter sql query and I am running query using pd.read_sql and showing results of it, but if user accidently add long running quqery than I want to stop running pd.read_sql query.
I tried to run it thread and stop thread but pd.read_sql keep running in backend it only stops if I stop running server is there a way to stop it?

Yes. Generally you must set a timeout period. Here is an examplr (using sqlite3)
import pandas as pd
import signal
import sqlite3  

class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass

def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException

def execute_query_with_timeout(query, conn, timeout=10):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    
    try:
        df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Query execution exceeded the time limit.")
        df = None
    finally:
        signal.alarm(0)
    
    return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db') 
    query = "SELECT * FROM your_table"  

    result = execute_query_with_timeout(query, conn, timeout=10)
    if result is not None:
        print(result)
    else:
        print("No results due to timeout or an error.")

But this also means that you need to hardcode that timeout. So, basically, you need to make an assessment of how long a query is allowed to take.

I tried it but as I am running code on windows   signal.alarm doesn't work.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html
signal.alarm(time)
If time is non-zero, this function requests that a SIGALRM signal be sent to the process in time seconds. Any previously scheduled alarm is canceled (only one alarm can be scheduled at any time). The returned value is then the number of seconds before any previously set alarm was to have been delivered. ....
Availability: Unix.
